# How do I generate tokens for the RandomPartitioner?

Tags: cassandra

I want to calculate and assign tokens to newly created Cassandra cluster with multi DC WITH Random Partitioner.

I am using OSS Apache Cassandra 1.0.12.
What formula can I use or is there a tool to generate it?

Expecting a formula or tool for multi DC token generator

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Comment: If you're building new apps/clusters, I'd strongly recommend you to go with C* 4.x. Also, there is 5.x that will be released just around the corner shortly. 1.0.x is sooo old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There used to be a simple Python script on the DataStax website that operators used for calculating tokens for `RandomPartitioner` but that was over 10 years ago now (2012) so a token generator tool was added in Cassandra 1.1.3 ([CASSANDRA-3709](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-3709)).

If you have C* 1.1 or 1.2 nodes available, you can just copy the script from the `tools/bin` directory and run it to generate tokens for a C* 1.0 cluster. Otherwise, you can get [a copy of the C* 1.1 `token-generator` here](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-1.1/tools/bin/token-generator) (GitHub repository).

To generate 10 tokens for a 10-node cluster, run:

```
$ tools/bin/token-generator 10
```

To generate tokens for a 3-DC cluster with 5 nodes each, run:

```
$ tools/bin/token-generator 5 5 5
```

I managed to locate an old copy of the help page from the DataStax Docs archive here if you're interested -- [Generating tokens in Cassandra 1.1](https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/1.1/docs/initialize/token_generation.html). Cheers!

Comment: Git hub code helped, Thanks